# What are some make-ahead crunchy/crispy components that keep fairly well?

Tags: storage, texture

I'm wondering if you have any advice on crispy/crunchy components that keep fairly well (for a decent amount of time), either in the fridge/freezer or at room temperature.

Occasionally, I'll make a batch of breadcrumbs or fried quinoa, which do work well, but I'm curious to hear if you have any other ideas.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Prawn crackers, AKA [shrimp crackers](http://www.exoticgroceries.com.au/product_info.php?products_id=23114).
You just fry them up in a little oil, then sprinkle with salt.
They're made using either wheat flour or tapioca. I prefer the tapioca.
Available at most Chinese, Vietnamese, etc. food stores; for cheap.
I guess they come precooked too. Never tried those, but would be concerned about oil going rancid.

Comment: Hadn't thought of this. I like it! How would you generally pair them with food? Or are they better alone?

Comment: Alone, or any of the lighter dips might do. Mild salsa, onion etc. Nuver tried hummus, but that might be a tasty combo.

Comment: Much appreciated. This is very helpful.